# All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead

Tags: mysql, debian

Стоит MySQL(5.7.22)
При установке скрипта AMXBANS- выдает 
"`All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead`"

Debian 7 x64[image: AMXBANS INSTALL]

Comment: Не имеет отношения ни к debian, ни, в общем-то, даже к mysql. Ошибка разработчика. Сильная ошибка. Вопросы разработчику той штуки, которую пытаетесь ставить.

Comment: Есть вопрос, есть ли выход в данной ситуации? Просто к примеру я видел что просто правят конфиги какие-то, и у них всё работает

Comment: Разбираться с разработчиком, разбираться с кодом. Ну или найти где готовый рецепт для исправления кода на нормальный. Попытка повесить primary key на null-поле - это грубая ошибка разработчика.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать разработчику программы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл решение, для тех кто использует AMXBANS нужно перед установкой заменить 
.../install/table.inc на новый( а именно: https://drop.me/on3bp4 )- вот он.